# How can I deploy the carrot2 web-app clustering my own data with lucene index

Tags: carrot2

When I was using the carrot2 web-app clustering my own data with lucene index,I found the result are not the same as my expected.

error one：
[In the results list on the right lists only the cluster file name without a matching text passages and file locations，I'm not sure what caused the problem, I guess maybe when I use lucene to create an index file format is wrong, or is my configuration carrot2 web-app project there is a problem, I hope someone can tell me the answer][sorry i can't po my picture for that,you can look the picture in error two.]

error two:
[I found my search results showed that "other topics" not only a specific topic, it bothers me. I think there might be a problem clustering algorithm or is the topic of test data I have provided too little reason.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqUBG.png)

[When I use the K-means clustering algorithm， the results came out a lot of topics, but no specific topic name but only the file name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ3aB.png)

If someone can answer my doubts, I would appreciate it so much,and your answer will be helpful.

this is my code for creating lucene index files:

```
  package test2;

import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFileNames;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.LongField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
import org.carrot2.source.lucene.SimpleFieldMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;


//lucene 4.9
public class LuceneDemo2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String indexDir = "D:\\data\\lucene\\odp\\index-all";
        String dataDir = "D:\\data";

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LuceneDemo2 indexer = new LuceneDemo2(indexDir);

        int numIndexed;
        try {
            numIndexed = indexer.index(dataDir,new TextFilesFilter());
        } finally {
            indexer.close();
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Indexing " + numIndexed + " files took " + (end-start) + " milliseconds.");
    }

    private IndexWriter writer;

    public LuceneDemo2(String indexDir) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDir));
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_4_9);
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_4_9,analyzer);
        config.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
        writer = new IndexWriter(directory,config);
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        writer.close();
    }

    public int index (String dataDir,FileFilter filter) throws Exception {
        File[] files = new File(dataDir).listFiles();

        //if(files == null) return writer.numDocs();
        for(File f: files) {
            if(!f.isDirectory()&&
                !f.isHidden()&&
                f.exists()&&
                f.canRead()&&
                (filter == null || filter.accept(f))) {
                indexFile(f);
            }
        }

        /*
        if(files == null) return writer.numDocs();
        for(int i=0;i<files.length&&files!=null;i++) {
            if(!files[i].isDirectory()&&
                !files[i].isHidden()&&
                files[i].exists()&&
                files[i].canRead()&&
                (filter == null || filter.accept(files[i]))) {
                indexFile(files[i]);
            }
        }
        */
        return writer.numDocs();
    }

    private static class TextFilesFilter implements FileFilter {
        public boolean accept(File path) {
            return path.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
        }   
    }

    private Document getDocument(File f) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Document document = new Document();
        document.add(new StringField("path",  f.getAbsolutePath(), Field.Store.YES));
        document.add(new LongField("modified", f.lastModified(), Field.Store.NO)); 
        document.add(new TextField("content", new FileReader(f)));
        document.add(new TextField("title", f.getName(), Field.Store.YES));

        return document;
    }

    private void indexFile(File f) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Indexing "+ f.getCanonicalPath());
        Document document = getDocument(f);
        writer.addDocument(document);
    }   
}
```

that's my indexing PDF files code(part of it):

```
private void indexFile(File f) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Indexing "+ f.getCanonicalPath());
        //Document d = LucenePDFDocument.getDocument(f);
        String executeStr = "D:\\xpdf\\xpdfbin-win-3.04\\bin64\\pdftotext.exe";
        String[] cmd = new String[]{executeStr,"-enc","UTF-8","-q",f.getAbsolutePath(),"-"};  
        String str = null ; 
        Process p = null ;     
        BufferedReader br = null ;  
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer() ;
        try {  
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) ;               
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(),"UTF-8")) ;    
            while((str = br.readLine() ) != null ){  
                sb.append(str).append("\n") ;  
            }               
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } finally{  
            if (br != null){  
                try {  
                    br.close() ;  
                } catch (IOException e) {  
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }  
            }  
        }  
        String content = sb.toString();
        Document document = new Document();
        document.add(new StringField("url",  f.getAbsolutePath(), Store.YES));
        document.add(new TextField("content", content,Store.YES));
        document.add(new TextField("title", f.getName(), Store.YES));
        writer.addDocument(document);
    }
```

Comment: Today I find the error one by changing 
document.add(new StringField("path",  f.getAbsolutePath(), Field.Store.YES));
to
document.add(new StringField("url",  f.getAbsolutePath(), Field.Store.YES));

Answer (score 1):

Carrot2 algorithms operate on the raw text of the documents, so all the content fields you'd like to cluster need to be stored (`Field.Store.YES`). To have your "content" field stored in the index, the easiest solution would be to read the contents of the corresponding file into a `String` and then use the [String-based constructor](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/TextField.html#TextField(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.apache.lucene.document.Field.Store)) of the `TextField` class.

Once you re-index your content and set Carrot2 to cluster based on your "title" and "content" fields, you should see some meaningful clusters.

Comment: Thank you for your patience to answer, I think I already know where the problem above. But now I met another thorny issue, would like to hear your opinion.

Comment: I currently need to create an index on a large number of PDF files, but when I use XPDF to read out my PDFs and create a "content" index fields,I find "content" field displays the meaningless numbers rather than a valid field (By the way,I use the software "luke"  to view),I tried many times，but all like this result, I would like to know why. I guess probably because PDF is not read plain text so there is a problem, but after I convert PDF directly into TXT and then read TXT still have this problem.Looking forward to your reply.